# Could not download IOS Simulator Xcode 12.4. Failed to download package from ADC. No valid accounts registered with Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, developer-tools

Macbook Air M1, get the error in Xcode 12.4:

> Could not download and install IOS 12.0 Simulator. Failed to download package from ADC. There are no valid accounts registered with Xcode that have the ability to access this resource. Contact Apple Developer Program Support to resolve account access issues.

I have never had this error on the previous Xcode and Macbook on intel chip. Please can you tell me how to solve it.

[image]

Comment: When this alert box came up, I clicked `details` button, and saw something like "The network connection was lost. Domain: NSURLErrorDomain Code: -1005". In my situation, it might be my network was unstable.

Answer (score 2):

Did you get this error after updating Xcode or did you do anything special ?

Maybe I'll recommend you to download Xcode from https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

Comment: Nothing special, just bought new MacBook M1, and set all developers tools and Xcode 12.4 from AppStore

Comment: I have exact same issue using new Macbook with M1 chip

Comment: Same issue on my Intel Macbook

Comment: Same issue on M1 MacBook Pro. Xcode version 13.1 (13A1030d) with macOS Monterey 12.0.1 while trying to download iOS 13.7 simulator.

Comment: However, restarting Xcode and this helped me now: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/674599?answerId=695556022#695556022